# Запись и чтение файла. Сохранение и загрузка игры

Tags: c

Метод `showSavedGames()`  показывает в консоли один и тот же сохраненный файл дважды, хотя в лог-файле сохраняется только один файл. Также (возможно, по этой причине) не работает метод `uploadGame`. Подскажите, в чем может быть проблема?

```
void saveGame(int round, int numOfPlayers, int pointToNextRound, Card
              playersCardsData[MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS][NUM_OF_CARDS], Player
              players[MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS])
{
    FILE* pFile;
    char fileName[15];
    printf("Please enter file's name: \n");
    scanf("%s", fileName);
    pFile = fopen("masterFile", "a");

    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file cannot be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        fprintf(pFile, "%s\n", fileName);
        fclose(pFile);
    }

    pFile = fopen(fileName, "w");

    if (pFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("The file cannot be opened\n");
    }
    else
    {
        // write everything to file:
        fprintf(pFile, "%d\n", round);
        fprintf(pFile, "%d\n", numOfPlayers);
        fprintf(pFile, "%d\n", pointToNextRound);

        //info about players
        for (int playerIndex = 0; playerIndex < numOfPlayers; playerIndex++)
        {
            fprintf(pFile, "%d %d %s", players[playerIndex].id,
                    players[playerIndex].score, players[playerIndex].name);

            //info about cards
            for (int cardIndex = 0; cardIndex < NUM_OF_CARDS; cardIndex++)
            {
                fprintf(pFile, " %d %d", playersCardsData[playerIndex]
                        [cardIndex].value, playersCardsData[playerIndex][cardIndex].suit);
            }//inner for

            fprintf(pFile, "\n");
        }//outer for

        fclose(pFile);
        //TODO: Do you want to continue y/n exit(0);
    }//else
}//saveGame

void showSavedGames()
{
    FILE* filep;
    filep = fopen("masterFile", "r");
    char savedGameFile[15];

    if (filep == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening the file. There are no saved games.\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\n\nGames that exist:\n");

        while (!feof(filep))
        {
            fscanf(filep, "%s", savedGameFile);
            printf("%s\n", savedGameFile);
        }

        printf("\n");
    }

    fclose(filep);
}

void uploadGame(int round, int numOfPlayers, int pointToNextRound,
                Card
                playersCardsData[MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS][NUM_OF_CARDS], Player
                players[MAX_NUM_OF_PLAYERS])
{
    FILE* filep;
    char nameOfTheFile[15];

    do
    {
        printf("\n\nPlease enter the file's name you want to upload: \n");
        scanf("%s", nameOfTheFile);
        filep = fopen(nameOfTheFile, "r");
    }
    while (filep == NULL);

    while (!feof(filep))
    {
        fscanf(filep, "%d", &round);
        fscanf(filep, "%d", &numOfPlayers);
        fscanf(filep, "%d", &pointToNextRound);

        for (int i = 0; i < numOfPlayers; i++)
        {
            fscanf(filep, "%d %d %s", &players[i].id, &players[i].score,
                   players[i].name);

            for (int j = 0; j < numOfPlayers; j++)
            {
                fscanf(filep, "%d %d", &playersCardsData[i][j].value,
                       &playersCardsData[i][j].suit);
            }
        }
    }

    fclose(filep);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Вот этот код

```
while (!feof(filep))
```

работает не так, как вы ждете. Признак конца файла выставляется только *после* неудачной попытки чтения за концом файла. Поэтому, даже когда вы реально стоите в конце файла - тело `while` все равно выполняется. Только все ваши чтения, увы, ничего не читают - а вы это (успешность чтения) не проверяете...

Этот код у вас в обеих функциях. Для начала измените его на верный, а уж потом будете смотреть, работает ли вторая функция или есть и другие ошибки.